# En json que recibo de api tiene objetos con ":" en el nombre, no puedo completar las pruebas porque me genera error de sintaxis postman

Tags: json, api, postman, test

Por favor si pueden ayudarme a cambiar los nombres o indexar de manera que no tenga que usasrlos nombres con los ":" (2 puntos)

El response es:

```
{
"tipo": "https://www.todolodemas",
"titu": "horror",
"detal": "falta info, vease a:Detallesdehorror",
"*a:Codigo*": "404",
"*a:Detallesdehorror*": [
    {
        "titulo": "falta info",
        "*a:sendero*": "formato y tal",
        "*a:Codigo*": "asdf.1234"
    }
]
```

};

Generando las pruebas en la pestaña test de postman me figura error de sintaxis al tratar de  usar el anidamiento:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();

pm.test("HttpCode 404", function () {
pm.response.to.have.status(404);
});

pm.test("asdf.1234 Codigo", function () {
    pm.expect(jsonData.a:Detallesdehorror.a:Codigo).to.eql("asdf.1234");
});

pm.test("Error Sendero correcto", function () {
    pm.expect(jsonData.a:Detallesdehorror.a:sendero).to.eql("formato y tal");
});
```

Los 2 puntos ":" me figuran subrayados desde que los escribo como error.
Intente fetch y parse pero o no son o no los supe usar bien, muchas gracias de antemano.

[image: Sintax error]

Comment: Te falta cerrar un paréntesis aqui: `pm.expect(jsonData.a:Detallesdehorror.a:Codigo.to.eql("asdf.1234");`

Comment: Gracias! ya lo edite. por favor tendras idea de lo de los 2 puntos? al margen de que me equivoque con el parentesis en otras prubas mesigue el sintax error y e slo unico subrayado como error. gracias

Comment: Intenta con `jsonData['a:Codigo']`.

Comment: Gracias! cree un arreglo con el response de postman y luego lo evalue por el valor del lugar. y efectivamaente va asi, Gracias! lo voya  prbar de esta amenra para ver si queda mas sencillo

Answer (score 0):

Esto funciona como una solucion porque permite usar los key de un json que tienen simbolos como : para sin generar errores de sintaxys al menos en postman

Solucion:

```
    var jsonTestPath = {
        "a:Detallesdehorror": [
                {
                       "a:sendero": "formato y tal"
                },
                {
                       "a:Codigo": "asdf.1234"
                }
            ]
}

pm.test("HttpCode 404", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(404);
}),

pm.test("Sendero error correcto", function () {
        pm.expect(jsonTestPath["a:Detallesdehorror"][0]["a:sendero"]).to.eql("formato y tal");
}),

pm.test("asdf.1234 errorCode Correct", function () {
    pm.expect(jsonTestPath["a:Detallesdehorror"][1]["a:Codigo"]).to.eql("asdf.1234");
});
```

Comment: Hola Ando, bien por publicar tu solución, para que sea acorde con el sitio, deberías explicar de que manera esto soluciona tu problema, de esa forma, tu solución puede servir a otros, gracias.

Comment: Respuesta editada, gracias!